# How can I delete one record form two tables?

Tags: sql, database

I was just wondering if I could be able to delete a record from two differnt tables.

I think I need a lookup statement but I am unsure on where to begin.

In both tables I have a field called CardID.

In my first table I have a statement which reads,

```
delete from Table1
where recordstatus = 2
and expiry <=(Select convert(varchar(8),today,112)
from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate())as today)aa)
```

then I need to delete the record from table 2.

Any help will be deeply apprecitated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `getdate()` puts it in SQL Server teritory, but it would be nice if we could have the structure of the tables, and how they are related.

Comment: sorry I am using Management Studio Express

Comment: The only relation is the CardID field, I basically want to a query to look at table 1's CardID field and if its not there delete all records with that ID number in table 2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (your_key) REFERENCES Table1 (your_key) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @deleted TABLE (CardID int);

delete from Table1
OUTPUT deleted.CardID INTO @deleted (CardID)
where recordstatus = 2
and expiry <=(Select convert(varchar(8),today,112)
from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate())as today)aa);

DELETE FROM Table2
FROM @deleted d
WHERE Table2.CardID = d.CardID;
```

When deleting from `Table1`, you also store the deleted `CardID` values into a table variable (the added `OUTPUT` clause). Then you use that list to delete from `Table2` accordingly.

If you *always* need to delete from the two tables synchronously, a trigger for delete on `Table1` would fit here better, I think.

Comment: but i have now seen that I have a string which contains the data CARDID, is there a way to include a like query to delete the record as I am having trouble with the second delete query as I have an error witht the from @deleted d,   thank you for your time

Comment: @Leigh: Do you mean `Table2.CardID` is actually a string and it is a list of CardID values? If so, what is the format of the list? As a wild guess, you can modify the last query's `WHERE` clause as `WHERE ',' + Table2.CardID + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(d.CardID AS varchar) + ',%'`, assuming Table1.CardID is still `int`. But otherwise I must say this change to your original post weighs as much as a new question.

Comment: no table 2 has a field called actionstring which contains the card id as well as other text , sorry if i have confused things

Comment: @Leigh: Does `table2` have `CardID` also?

Comment: unfortuntly no, table 2 has a sting field that contains the card id inside eg user(02235666)changed -the number being the card ID i need to look at

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't want to issue two different queries ? This would be the easiest solution. I guess what's preventing you from doing so is that you might not have the correct primary/foreign keys structure in place on your database.

If you really want to use only one query, you might want to look into triggers and/or cascade updates

Comment: well I guess I could use two different queries. How could I write the 2nd one

Comment: To answer this, I think we really need to know more about your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM Table2 
WHERE  CardID IN (SELECT CardID from Table1 
    where recordstatus = 2 and expiry <=
    (Select convert(varchar(8),today, 112) 
    from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) as today) aa ));

delete from Table1 where recordstatus = 2 
and expiry <=(Select convert(varchar(8),today, 112)
    from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) as today) aa );
```

Comment: Thbak you so much for replying. In table two I do not have record status, sorry for being unclear. I basically need to say look at the first table if a CARDID is not there delete all records relating to that card ID. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE t2 from table2 as t2 join table1 as t1 on t1.CardID=t2.CardID where t1.recordstatus = 2
and t1.expiry <=(Select convert(varchar(8),today,112)
from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate())as today)aa)
this will be your first delete query to delete records from the table2 and then use your original query to delete records from table1... and in this query if i missed any field then add t1. before that like i added t1.expiry